# c# Strong Typed DataSet set default on Parameter

Tags: c#, ado.net, strongly-typed-dataset

Is there a way to set de defaults on some fields in a strongly typed dataset by code.
I would prefer to to it generally, not in each insert using the dataset.
Ex CRE_DATE, CRE_USER ....
Where should I place my code ?

Comment: What technology are you using?  Do you have a model class?

Comment: C# in VS2012, Strong typed DataSets.